# Printing a list with specific seperations

Tags: python, list

I have been working for a small program that in the end creates a list with 100 randomized numbers in it. I am supposed to print the list in a 10x10 space, and, since I'm a newbie in code I can't really wrap my head around how to do it. Any suggestions?

could look like this:

```
list1 = [0]*100
```

and end result should look like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For-loops should help here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's supposed to happen if you have all zeroes and one item is a 10? Are all entries supposed to be aligned, or do you just want to print one 10-items sublist per line?

Comment: Take a look at the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us in the question itself, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you considered structuring your list as a 10x10 list of lists instead of one 100 items list? This will make the printing super easy

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with two for loops. something like this:

```
import random
final_list =[]
for i in range(0, 10):
    row_list = []
    for j in range(0, 10):
        row_list.append(random.randint(1, 10000))
    final_list.append(row_list)
```

break down:

1. you could use a library called random for creating a random number. you can look at its document [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).
2. in `random.randint(1, 10000)` I gave a range which is the range of random numbers. you could change it to suit your requirements.
3. there might be some better way to do this but it's more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is just the built-in function [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#print):

```
print(*(list1[i: i + 10] for i in range(0, len(list1), 10)), sep='\n')
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

maybe the code is a bit complicated since you are trying to learn but I will try to explain:

- there is a generator that splits your initial list into smaller lists of 10 elements:

  (list1[i: i + 10] for i in range(0, len(list1), 10))
- then I'm using unpack operator `*` to unpack the generator into `print` arguments
- I'm separating each list by a new line using `sep='\n'`

---

a more simple version to achieve your end result is to use a single `for` loop:

```
for index in range(0, len(list1), 10):
    print(list1[i: i + 10])
```

ouptu:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I sadly dont understand the code so i will not be using this, but still, thanks you for the suggestion and for trying to explain it!

Comment: @flexan_kodar what about now? I added a more simple solution

Comment: Thank you, now it's easier for me to get behind! Im still a lttle confused about what list1[i: i + 10] does but i think i have some general understanding.

Comment: list1[i: i + 10] is using slicing, "cutting" the list at a given start-end position in list, you can have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: I will have a look at that, thank you again for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I have pretty much solved the problem, at least to my satisfacion, it looks like this:

```
example_list = [0]*100

index_print = 0

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        print(example_list[index_print], end=' ')
        index_print += 1
    print('\n')
```

Could be inporved, and i will probably do that too, but right now im satisfied.
Sadly i have discovered some problems with my code that i have not solved yet, but thats for anoher question. Thanks for the many answers, would not have expected to get so many on my first post!

Comment: rather than print element by element, you could slice the initial list